# How to sort an unordered linked list

Tags: java, arrays

Hello i need to sort this unordered linked list of objects using a selection sort. But i need to convert the unordered list to an array to use the sort and i dont know how to set it. Then after i need to add the array back into the unordered linked list. here is my code

```
LinkedUnorderedList <games> c1 = new LinkedUnorderedList <>();
// stack for the code 3
LinkedListStack <games> transactions = new LinkedListStack <games> ();
//Stack for the copy
ArrayStack <games> copyA = new ArrayStack <games> ();

Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
int code;
String name;
String rt;
String dev;
int year;
games obj;
games tobj;

while(fileScan.hasNext())
{    
    code = fileScan.nextInt();
        if(code == 3)
        {    
            name = fileScan.next();
            dev = fileScan.next();
            year = fileScan.nextInt();
            rt = fileScan.next();
            tobj = new games(name,dev);
            transactions.push(tobj);
        }    
        else
        {    
            name = fileScan.next();
            dev = fileScan.next();
            //System.out.print("hello");
            year = fileScan.nextInt();
            rt = fileScan.next();
            obj = new games(name,dev,year,rt);
            c1.addToRear(obj);
        }
} 
System.out.print(c1.toString());
Iterator <games> cpy = c1.iterator();
games element;
while(cpy.hasNext())
{
    element = cpy.next();
    copyA.push(element);

} 
cpy = c1.iterator();
    while(cpy.hasNext())
    {
    info += cpy.next();
    }    

String ar [] = new String [c1.count];
for(int index = 0; index < c1.count;index++)
{
    ar[index] = c1[index];
}
```

Comment: Specify language that way people looking for question in language they know will help you with this `arrays` tag is very generaly and not likly to be found

Answer (score 0):

Your question really only asks how to convert between arrays and lists, not how to sort them.  Here is some pointers to Java's standard library regarding converting lists to arrays and vice-versa.

All collections (all forms of list and other collections) in the Java Collections framework have a method on them [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-) that converts the collection to an array.

Another useful part of the framework is the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class.  It has an [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-) method that accepts a `Collection` and an array and adds the elements from the array to the collection for you.

When working with arrays, you'll want to be familiar with the handy [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.  One of the handy methods it provides is [`asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) which returns a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation which contains all of the elements in the array you provide.  This can be useful, for example, in conjunction with the [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) that all of the collections have.

Answer (score 0):

**For primitive type :**

```
Collections.sort(myPrimitiveList);
Collections.reverse(myPrimitiveList);

Arrays.sort(myPrimitiveArray);
Arrays.sort(myPrimitiveArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

**For other object :**

```
Collections.sort(myListOfObject, new Comparator<myObject>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(myObject obj1, myObject obj2) {
                    int cmp = obj1.compareTo(obj2);

                    if (cmp > 0) {
                        return obj1;
                    } else {
                        return obj2;                        
                    }
                }
            });
```